# Can't get TextView to fill parent height in ListView in a dialog

Tags: android, layout

In my Android app, I pop up a dialog showing a ListView. The problem I am having is getting the textview height to fill the parent. I want it to fill the parent and then center the text vertically. Instead, it appears to wrap the height. Here is the xml for the dialog:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ViewSwitcher xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/loadSwitcher"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="#ff484a4a"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:tag="LoadingView" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:gravity="center" >

            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/marker_progress"
                style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:indeterminate="true" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/msg_PleaseWait"
            android:textSize="18sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llContent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:tag="ContentView" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvHeader"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
            android:background="#7395bf"
            android:padding="3dp"
            android:text="@string/lbl_SelectLocationSet"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/lvData"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:minHeight="50dp"
            android:background="#ff626262"
            android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
            android:divider="#ff7f7f7f"
            android:dividerHeight="1dp"
            android:scrollingCache="true" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/llToolbar"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#cacaca"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
            android:paddingTop="5dp" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnOK"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/lbl_ButtonOK"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnCancel"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/lbl_ButtonCancel"
                android:textSize="16sp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</ViewSwitcher>
```

And here is the xml for a row in the listview:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/rbSelected"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:checked="false"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp" >
    </RadioButton>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivEncrypted"
        android:layout_width="16dp"
        android:layout_height="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/rbSelected"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/icon_lock_16x16" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvDate"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:background="#baf5c7"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/ivEncrypted"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: from my own experience I know that a Dialog´s parent view will always wrap_content, so a match_parent has no effect in a child view. Instead, You have to do some static sizes with dp unit. This has to be done for multiple screen sizes

Answer (score 1):

To get a TextView to fill its parent, I found that by placing it in a LinearLayout and setting the layout_centerVertical to true does the job. RelativeLayouts have a problem with fill_parent. Originally I thought this problem was for dialogs only but it does in fact occur for activities as well.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/rbSelected"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:checked="false"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:focusable="false"        
        android:paddingLeft="5dp" >
    </RadioButton>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivEncrypted"
        android:layout_width="16dp"
        android:layout_height="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/rbSelected"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/icon_lock_16x16" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/ivEncrypted" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvDate"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="18sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```